How to create prefix matches in Istio VirtualService for substring paths
I'm encountering a warning message about duplicate/overlapping matches in my Istio VirtualService configuration, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. Here's the warning message:
Warning: virtualService rule #1 match #0 of prefix /apparchived/ is not used (duplicate/overlapping match in rule #1 of prefix /app on #0)

I have a VirtualService configuration where I need to route requests for paths /app and /apparchived to different services while preserving the URI paths. However, I'm facing issues with overlapping matches in my configuration.
Here's my current VirtualService configuration:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: ingress-routes
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - dev-app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/app/"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/app"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app.app.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/apparchived/"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/apparchived"        
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: apparchived.app.svc.cluster.locala
          number: 80

I'd like to achieve the following routing behavior:

Requests to /app should be routed to service app.app.svc.cluster.local.
Requests to /apparchived should be routed to service apparchived.app.svc.cluster.local.
At the same time /app/ & /apparchived/ also should route to respective services.
Any insights on how to resolve the warning and achieve the desired routing behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Please use "exact" and "prefix" attributes combination to achieve desired routing you are looking for.  Please use below virtual service definition to avoid "duplicate/overlapping match in rule warning"
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: ingress-routes
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - dev-app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/app/"
    - uri:
        exact: "/app"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: app.app.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/apparchived/"
    - uri:
        exact: "/apparchived"        
    rewrite:
      uri: "/"        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: apparchived.app.svc.cluster.local
          number: 80


Issue is because of the order of the lines in yaml file. I am creating /app route first in file and then /apparchived. I am able to solve this by moving /apparchived order to before /app.
